# Redux: Importing action creator into another causes typeError 'x is not a function'

Tags: reactjs, redux, action

I am facing a typeError which really confuses me and drives me kinda mad:

I have an car action creator:

```js
import * as dispatchTypes from '../helper/dispatchTypes';
import { notifyBuyer } from  './buyer';

export const addCar = () => async dispatch => {
  const response = await fetch(someUrl, someBody)

  if (response.ok) {
    const car = await response.json();
    dispatch({type: dispatchTypes.ADD_CAR_RESPONSE, car});
    return notifyBuyer()(dispatch);
  };
}
```

I have an action creator for notifyBuyer() within a buyer.js as well:

```js
...
export const notifyBuyer = () => async dispatch => {
...
```

Finally, I am calling the notifyBuyer() within a React component as well:

```js
import * as actions from '../../actions/buyer';

class WhateverComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  doSomething = event => {
    if (!event.disabled) {
      this.props.notifyBuyer(event.toString());
    }
  };

  render() {...}

}

export const StyledComponent = withStyles(styles)(WhateverComponent);
export default connect(
  state => ({}),
  {notifyBuyer: actions.notifyBuyer}
)(StyledComponent);
```

If I run the app and make the doSomething function run, I get the following **error**:

```js
TypeError: _this.props.notifyBuyer is not a function
```

The interesting thing is: 
If I remove the **"import { notifyBuyer } from  './buyer';"** from car.js everything is fine. 
But as soon the import is set in the file, the props of the Whatever-Component do not hold the notifyBuyer() function any longer and the typeError is thrown.

Comment: Your action must be a function but not const also you need to use prop-type library to define prop types. Take a look at this https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types

Comment: it looks fine, are you sure you use the `default` exported component ?. be sure you have `import MyComponent from './WhateverComponent'` and not `import  {StyledComponent} from './WhateverComponent'`, can you show us the code where you use this connected component ?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé The Whatever-Component is correctly imported into the parent component.
`import WhateverComponent from './WhateverComponent';
...
<Grid item md={12} lg={12} xl={12}>
                <WhateverComponent />
              </Grid>`

Comment: @Think-Twice
We are using const throughout the whole project, it always worked. Moreover, it should work without prop types as well.

Comment: Did you try to use the connected component inside the `withStyles` => `withStyles(styles)(connect(...)(WhateverComponent))`

Answer (score 0):

I think the export used in the connect function is look like wrong. Use the below sample code and check it out.

```
export default connect(
  state => ({}),
  dispatch => ({notifyBuyer: dispatch(actions.notifyBuyer)})
)(StyledComponent);
```

Comment: it's useless, mapDispatchToProps accepts an object and will wraps the functions into a `dispatch`,  so your code is essentially the same as the author

Comment: @Olivier No, you absolutely are wrong. The redux connect function accepts two parameters as a functions. But in the sample code there is JSON object in the second parameter.

Comment: please read the doc https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options the second parameter can be a function or an object

Comment: @OlivierBoissé accepted. Sorry for misunderstanding:)

Comment: @kumark I have a lot of those components in our projects and providing an object does totally work